# über die Temperaturen reden

Tags: preposition

Ich habe Probleme, diese Sätze zu verstehen.

> a) Die Temperaturen steigen ***auf bis zu*** 20 Grad.
> b) Die Temperaturen steigen ***auf*** 20 Grad.
> c) Die Temperaturen sind ***um*** 20 Grad.

Comment: In a generic question like this, additional context is always welcome and typically provokes better answers. What do you understand? Is it just the difference in meaning between the examples? Apart from that *sind* is a bit boring choice in example c, since it is also heavily used as auxiliary verb elsewhere; I would choose *liegen* instead.

Comment: @guidot♦ why you answer in English, when the question is in German??

Comment: @SwissCodeMen happens to all of us.

Comment: Sentence c) is incomplete. No one can understand it without the missing "gestiegen".

Comment: @KilianFoth Es kann bei c) auch gemeint sein, dass die Temperaturen bei ca. 20 Grad liegen und nicht um 20 Grad gestiegen sind.

Comment: Statt c) würde ich bevorzugen "Die Temperaturen liegen um die 20 Grad."

Answer (score 3):

a) An unterschiedlichen Orten (im Bereich der Vorhersage) steigen die Temperaturen unterschiedlich weit an. An einigen Orten kann die Temperatur 20 Grad erreichen, wärmer wird es aber nirgends.

b) Die Temperatur steigt überall auf genau 20 Grad.

c) Alle Temperaturen liegen zwischen etwa 17,5 und 22,5 Grad.*

---

*Anmerkung*

* Meiner Wahrnehmung nach unterteilen Menschen metrische Skalen gedanklich zunächst in 10er-, dann in 5er-Schritte. Man kann diese orientierende Grobeinteilung gut auf Zollstöcken und Linealen sehen, wo jeweils die ganzen Zentimeter (also alle Vielfachen von 10 mm) durch einen langen Strich gekennzeichnet sind, die 5 mm dazwischen (5, 15, 25 mm usw.) durch einen Strich mittlerer Länge und die einzelnen Millimeter durch einen kurze Striche:

[image: Lineal]

Temperaturen, wie Längen, werden, wenn von ihnen nur grob und ungefähr die Rede ist, deshalb oft auf 0°, 5°, 10°, 15°, 20°, 25° usw. bezogen: "Es ist um die fünfzehn Grad." Aufgrund der grob orientierenden Unterteilung in 5er-Schritten, wird die maximale Ausdehnung dieses ungefähren Temperaturbereichs – in der Regel und ungefähr – durch die arithmetischen Mittel dieser 5er-Schritte begrenzt: *Um die zwanzig Grad* muss für die meisten Sprecher näher an 20° liegen als an 15° und 25°. Daraus ergibt sich: `17,5° > um 20° > 22,5°`.

Als wie weit der Temperaturbereich von *um die x Grad* empfunden wird, ist jedoch individuell verschieden und vom jeweiligen Kontext abhängig. Manche Menschen sehen *um die zwanzig Grad* als 20±2, andere als 20±3 an, und wenn man von Temperaturen auf dem Mars im Vergleich zu Temperaturen auf der Venus spricht, mag *um die x Grad* auch ±50° meinen (weil die gedankliche Referenzskala einen weiteren Temperaturbereich umfasst und entsprechend gröber unterteilt ist).

Temperaturbereiche um andere Zahlen werden entsprechend weit oder eng empfunden. Das heißt der Bereicht *um dreiundzwanzig Grad* ist für den jeweiligen Sprecher genauso weit wie der Bereich *um zwanzig Grad*, also beispielsweise 23±2 und 23±2.

Comment: Wer sagt, das "um 20 Grad" = "Temperaturen zwischen etwa 17 und 23 Grad" sind ( +- 3 Grad)? Denke für c) wäre passender: "Alle Temperaturen liegen im Bereich von 20 Grad"

Comment: @fluctuatingpsychosis *5er-Potenzen* Du meinst 5er-Schritte. 5er-Potenzen wäre *hoch 5*.

Comment: @besc Ups, ja, danke. Mathe halt ...

Comment: @besc: Auch nicht. 5er-Potenzen sind Potenzen zur Basis 5, also 5°, 5¹, 5² usw.

Comment: "Die Temperaturen sind um 20 Grad" bedeutet, dass es eine gewisse Ungenaugkeit gibt - aber es nicht möglich, diese auf den willkürlichen Bereich 17,5 bis 22,5 Grad festzulegen. Wie wäre es denn bei "Die Temperaturen sind um 18 Grad"?

Comment: @PaulFrost Zum einen ist der Bereich nicht willkürlich gewählt. Ich erkläre genau, wie ich auf die Zahlen komme. Ich bin überzeugt, dass die meisten Sprecher **im Alltag** bei *um zwanzig Grad* nicht Abweichungen von vier oder mehr grad meinen, und auch nicht Abweichungen von einem Grad oder weniger. Die meisten werden ±2 oder ±3 denken. Im Mittel ist das aber eben gerade ±2,5. Zum anderen habe ich bereits am Beispiel von 23 Grad beantwortet, wie es mit 18 Grad wäre.

Comment: @userunknown Ups. Ja, klar, danke! Natürlich *5 hoch irgendwas*. Da war ich wohl nicht ganz wach.

Answer (score -1):

Die Version c ist falsch. Richtig wäre eine dieser beiden Versionen

> c1) Die Temperaturen **steigen** um 20 Grad.
> c2) Die Temperaturen **sind** um 20 Grad **gestiegen.**

Ich werde c1 anstelle von c verwenden, weil diese Version die Gegenwart verwendet, so wie auch a und b.

**a) Die Temperaturen steigen auf bis zu 20 Grad.**

Obergrenze

Das bedeutet, dass die Temperaturen ansteigen. Nehmen wir an, es habe jetzt 10°C. Dann bedeutet diese Aussage, dass die Temperatur nirgendwo im Land bei 10°C bleibt, sondern dass es überall wärmer als 10°C werden wird. Es ist aber unklar, wie warm genau es werden wird. Es ist aber ausgeschlossen, dass es mehr als 20°C sein werden. Mögliche Tageshöchstwerte sind z.B. 12°C, 15°C oder vielleicht 18°C. In einigen wenigen Regionen des Landes kann das Thermometer im Laufe des Tages aber sogar 20°C anzeigen. Es ist aber ausgeschlossen, dass es irgendwo noch wärmer wird.

**b) Die Temperaturen steigen auf 20 Grad.**

genauer Zielwert

Das ist eine klare (aber unglaubwürdige) Ansage. Das bedeutet nämlich, dass der Tageshöchstwert überall genau 20°C sein wird. Es gibt keinen Ort, an dem der Höchstwert des Tages 19°C oder weniger sein wird, und es gibt keinen Ort, an dem die Temperatur auf 21°C oder mehr ansteigt.

**b) Die Temperaturen steigen um 20 Grad.**

Differenz

In a und b wurde die Temperatur angegeben, die erreicht wird (entweder als Obergrenze eines Intervalls, oder exakt). In c wird eine Temperaturdifferenz angegeben, die zur aktuellen Temperatur zu addieren ist um den Endwert zu erhalten. Wenn es jetzt 4°C hat, werden es später 24°C sein, also um 20 °C mehr. Wenn es hingegen jetzt schon 18°C hat, wird die Temperatur auf 38°C ansteigen.

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht, wieso du meinst, die Variante c) sei falsch. Temperaturen können doch *um die x Grad* sein?

Comment: "Die Temperaturen sind um 20 Grad" verstehe ich im Sinne "es ist ca. 20 Grad warm". Anderes Beispiel: "Der PC kostet um die 500 Euro". Vielleicht ist der österreichische Sprachgebrauch hier anders. Falls ja, wäre eine Ergänzung der Anwort sinnvoll.